# Will the judgement from England's Central Criminal Court be made available to the public?

Tags: united-kingdom

I've found an interesting piece of news: https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/mar/09/man-charged-with-leeds-terror-offences-appears-in-court

> The charges allege that Golaszewski was found with copies of 21 Silent Techniques of Killing by Master Hei Long, The Anarchist Cookbook and The Big Book of Mischief on 23 February in Leeds. It is also alleged that he had in his possession the Improvised Munitions Handbook, Murder Inc, The Book by Jack the Rippa, and Minimanual Of The Urban Guerilla, by Carlos Marighella.

The article mentions the hearing date:

> He was remanded in custody to appear at the Old Bailey on 15 March.

Guardian article mentions 6 books, the Independent article mentions 6 counts: https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/crime/pawel-golaszewski-uk-terror-leeds-arrest-right-wing-a8815116.html

> Pawel Golaszewski faces six counts under the Terrorism Act and has been charged with possession of a document or record "containing information of a kind likely to be useful to a person committing or preparing an act of terrorism".

**Will the judgment be available to the public?**

I'm specifically interested in the link between possession of the books (some of them available on amazon.com) and terrorist charges - what other evidence has been gathered and how it was evaluated.

---

Micro research:

- The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Bailey is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Court - do all of the judgments are released to the public?
- https://www.judiciary.uk/judgments/ - I'm worried only a small portion of judgments lands on this website.

---

From the website: https://www.thelawpages.com/court-hearings-lists/Central-Criminal-Court.php

[image]

It appears that it could be more involved than the possession of 6 books.

Answer (score 2):

All of the judgements are released to the public (I am prepared to believe there are a very few national security cases where that is not the case - but this won't be one of them).

However that release may only consist of the jury foreman/forewoman standing up in open court and saying "Guilty" or "Not Guilty".  If the public want to learn about the judgement, they will need to be in the court or hope that there is a reporter present who decides to write a story about it.

If you want to learn the prosecution and defence arguments, I am pretty sure you have to be in court during the trial.

If you want to learn why the jury made the decision they did, that is not possible, and would be highly illegal.

Finally, if you want to learn the sentencing remarks by the judge (assuming the defendant is found guilty) then *some* of those are published, but by no means all.

Comment: is there any indication that this is a jury trial at this stage? Preliminary hearings don't have them iirc.